# how do i rewrite this ternary operator in C?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

How do I write in a loop instead of a ternary operator ?

```
 temp->status = (inStore ? waiting : called);
```

would it be like:

```
if (inStore){

  return waiting;

}

else (

  return called;

}
```

I'm unsure becauseI get an error doing this, I'm using it in a void function

Comment: `if (inStore) temp->status = waiting; else temp->status = called;` will be equivalent to the first code. I don't see any relation with loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:  `else (`.  Change the `(` to `{` and your compile should be clean.

The [ternary operator](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/c/ternary) is simply an `if-then-else` statement in a shortcut syntax, with the assignment statement presented as its single `lvalue`.  So:

```
temp->status = (inStore ? waiting : called);
```

is translated to:

```
if(inStore == true)
{
    temp->status = waiting;
}
else
{
    temp->status = called;
}
```

Note that there is nothing wrong with your syntax (except maybe the `"("` here:  `else (`).  In a function, it might be preferable to use `return` statements if the function required no clean up before leaving.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `waiting` or `called` to `temp->status` variable instead of returning it, also in `else` you used parenthesis wrongly. Whole thing should be:

```
if (inStore)
    temp->status = waiting;
else
    temp->status = called;
```

I am not sure why you asked for a loop in that case, as there is no need to use one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(inStore){
   temp->status = waiting;
} else { // there was a ( instead of a {
   temp->status = called;
}
```